# Sikuli or AutoIT - which one is better?

Tags: selenium, ui-automation, autoit, sikuli

AutoIT and Sikuli both supports windows based automation. But I dont have much experience on both. I would like to know the major differences between each other and which one is efficient. Kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: Post it in https://sqa.stackexchange.com/... You will have better luck there

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Obviously [pywinauto](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto) + [lackey](https://github.com/glitchassassin/lackey) is better. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sikuli mainly use image based identification and comparison. Mainly use for recording things like flash object. It is helpful where you dont have object ids or locator.

AutoIT is used for simulated keystrokes, mouse movement and window/control. Mostly window base applications like commonly seen window based authentication.

Now, it depends what you have to work with, based on that you can select.